# cbind over several dataframes with colnames in string vector

Tags: r

I would like to have the same outcome for test2 as in test1 but with the use of the "colname" variable. (mainly just combining a, b and c to the same dataframe). just tried for a long time but no success. any ideas?

```
a <-  c(1:3)
b <-  c(4:6)
c <-  c(7:9)

colname <- c("a","b","c")

test1 <- cbind(a,b,c)

test2 <- cbind(colname)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `do.call` with `mget`.

```
(test2 <- do.call(cbind, mget(colname)))
#     a b c
#[1,] 1 4 7
#[2,] 2 5 8
#[3,] 3 6 9

identical(test1, test2)
#[1] TRUE
```